# How would I generate a LRD & ludocid for google search

Tags: google-places-api

I've been digging all around the web and can't figure out how to generate a LRD and ludocid. I'm trying to create a simple review link generator but can't seem to get anything of it. I know the procedure of viewing page source etc but I'm trying to make it so it automatically gets it from the input..

Comment: half a year later still can't find a real programatic solution. did you?

Comment: @j_walker_dev I have, using the place_id instead of the ludocid

Comment: Shit, i wish i saw this before. I have the place_id. What do you do with it?

Comment: I managed to generate the review link using the place ID, although I currently don't have a computer near me as I'm on holiday

Comment: @j_walker_dev scratch that, the way I made the review link is by doing the following: https://search.google.com/local/writereview?place_id=[place_id]

Comment: That is great. Using that strategy is it still possible to pre fill 5 stars like you can with the LRD urls? Also, how did you find the place_id link? I would love to see some docs on it but i never can find any.

Answer (score -1):

This blog post explains both: https://www.theedesign.com/blog/2016/how-to-create-a-google-review-url-with-the-new-g-layout

Comment: [Link-only answers are not acceptable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/380598) on Stack Exchange sites, and [Stack Overflow in particular](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168714/380598).